# Python return values were not expected in the table

Tags: python, flask

In my python program I got a list of values and a dictionary for example

```
values= ['1','2','3','4','5']
dic = {'1': Some Value1, '2': Some Value2, '3': Some Value3}
```

I want to return all the matching values in the dic to a table with one condition i.e., my values should not repeat for example:
 What I need is:

```
Row: 1 Some Values 1
Row: 2 Some values 2
Row: 3 Some values 3
Row: 4 Empty
Row: 5 Empty
```

But what I am getting while returning the value in the 3 row table is:

```
Row 1: Some Values 1,Some values 2, Some values 3
Row 2: Some Values 1,Some values 2, Some values 3
Row 3: Some Values 1,Some values 2, Some values 3
```

And my function is:

```
def value(self):
  values = ['1','2','3','4','5']
  dic = {'1': Some Value1, '2': Some Value2, '3': Some Value3}
  for keys, values in dic.items():
    if(keys == values):
    return values
```

My second function simply looks like this:

```
def get_value(self):
 element=classA()
 element.value()
```

but when I call this function from another, its returning all the values in the same row and repeats the process for all the rows, can someone help me with this, thanks

Comment: Can you show the calling code? There are a number of things wrong with your code. 1) you are redefining `values`, 2) you are returning as soon as you find a match, 3) your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Your `value()` function will not return anything unless the `keys` and `values` in the `dic` are equal. So unlikely you are getting this output from this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
l = []
for i in values:
    if i in dic.keys():
        l.append(f'ROW:{i} {dic[i]}')
    else:
        l.append(f'ROW:{i} Empty')
return l
```

`l` will be the list of the output that you desired.

remember that the `values` is you list of elements, so when you say `for keys, values in ...` these values will be overrides the others.

Note that:

> for these *formated staring* you should have **Python3.6** or higher.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, for your answer, but it works as expected with the print statement. Actually, I am using the return statement to return to another function. Which is printing only the first value five times. This is the output in all the rows: 1 1 1 1 1, but how can I return all the values. Thanks

Comment: @user3762116 I update my answer. let me know that you want any changes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `values` is redefined, you should use other variable name. In addition, you use the `==` which means it would return values only if the value of `keys` and the value of `values` is equal, I think you can use `in`. And then, `else` can be used after your `if`.